# upgrading my computer system for office use

Tags: upgrade

Presently I have the under-mentioned computer system. What should be changed and upgraded with the following products that I own presently?  I am interested in performance issues related to cache memory, bus speed, RAM, CAS latency as well as other considerations. Thanks for your help.

- **Processor (CPU):** Intel Celeron Dual Core E3300 2.5 GHz
- **Motherboard:** Asus P5QPL-AM G41
- **Main Memory (RAM):**   2 GB Team Elite DDR2 PC8000
- **Case:**    Coolermaster RC330
- **Power Supply Unit:**   500W EZ-Cool Standard
- **Storage Device (Hard Drive):** 500GB Samsung
- **Video Card:**  Intel GMA X4500 (On-board)
- **Optical Drive:**   LG GH22NS50
- **Sound Card:**  AC 97 (On – board)
- **Card Reader:** Akasa Black
- **TFT Monitor:** 19” View Sonic
- **Speakers:**    Logitech S120 2.0

Answer (score 1):

The single best and most cost effective thing to upgrade is the RAM Max that bad boy out. That will give you the most bang for the buck. That mother board supports up to 8GB of RAM. If you are using a 32-Bit Operating System then you should not exceed 4GB as anything above that is a waste of money since the OS cannot use it. if you are going with a 64-Bit OS which I recommend then you will be able to use all 8GB of RAM and that will be very nice you will have a speedy system.

But if you want to add a little more oomph to you system i would also recommend tossing in a faster processor maybe the Core 2 Quad (LGA775).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention operating system, but there are two things I would suggest.  One is to boost your RAM.  If you have Windows XP or 32bit Vista/Win 7, then go to 4 GB of RAM total.  If you have access to 64 bit Vista/Win 7 then I would push it up to the max for your motherboard, which is 8GB of RAM.

The second thing I would do is add a second hard drive (or replace the existing 500GB) with one or two 2TB SATA HDD drives.  You can never have enough storage space, even for an office environment.

For office usage, you really don't need to boost anything else.  If you have to choose one or the other option, go with the hard drives.  Nowadays, 500GB runs out pretty quickly.

Comment: I would have to disagree with you on the hard drive bit. I find that most people in the office can skate by with 500GB and quite frankly less than 250GB... In situations like my stent working at Fox Studios where large media files where everywhere the 2TB External drives where everywhere. I just don’t think those large hard drives are needed in the office unless you are dealing with large media (as part of you job that is).

Comment: @jamason1983 - You must not work in my office.  :)  Between my local and NAS storage, I have well over 1 TB of work related data and often have more than that as work related projects come and go.  But I will agree that it depends on the work being done.

Comment: Wow that is a lot of data. I am a data hog at home I collect VM's and that kind of data just balloons out of control. When it comes to work related data I am a big fan of have it on a server and have it backed up... I have just been burned way too many times (apparently I didn’t learn the first few times). So I tend to shuffle files around and usually have active project only on my computer and have automated scripts to copy changed files every 30 min. I have grown to distrust computers, other, and myself with important data.